# Application.OnTime not executed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cancel a timer in the Workbook_Close routine in the ThisWorkbook module.  Can anyone explain the following behaviour?:

***Closing the workbook manually***
Application.OnTime functions as expected and cancels the timer.
If I try to kill the same timer more than once, or a non-existent timer, I get an error

> ERROR: 1004: Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed

To me, this is supporting evidence that the function is working properly.

***Closing the Workbook using ThisWorkbook.Close***
The timer is not killed as evidenced by the facts that:

1. The workbook re-opens when the timer expires
2. VBA does not throw any error if the same timer is killed more than once
3. VBA does not throw an error on attempting to kill a non-existent timer

***Further Context***

Application.Run fires as expected in both cases.  To me this indicates that the Application Object is still loaded and the VBA Runtime is still functioning properly.

***Test Code***

In a standard Module called minUnit

```
Private Sub testCallBack(name As String, nextTime As String)
  MsgBox "callback " & name & " " & nextTime
End Sub

Public Function sProcedure(callBackProcedure As String, mName As String, nextTime As Date) As String
' Constructs a properly formatted string to feed to OnTime for a call back with two parameters
  sProcedure = "'" & callBackProcedure & " " & """" & mName & """," & """" & fmtTime(nextTime) & """'"
End Function

Private Sub testTimerSet()
  gnextTime = Now() + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
  Application.OnTime gnextTime, sProcedure("Globals.testCallBack", _
                                            "testTimer", gnextTime)
End Sub

Public Sub testTimerKill()
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.OnTime gnextTime, sProcedure("Globals.testCallBack", _
                                           "testTimer", gnextTime), _
                                          , False
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

  Globals.testTimerKill
  Globals.testTimerKill
  Globals.testTimerKill

  On Error Resume Next

  Application.OnTime 0, "Nothing", , False

  Application.Run sProcedure("minUnit.testCallBack", "Application.Run", Now())

  Application.OnTime Now(), sProcedure("minUnit.testCallBack", "Application.OnTime Now()", Now()), , True

End Sub

Sub closeWorkbook()
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Trace for manual closing (errors thrown as expected)...

> ```
> 20:27:07:206 minUnit.testTimerSet:  START
> 20:27:07:209  Application.OnTime 'minUnit.testCallBack "testTimer","21:27:07"'                     :0.003532
> 20:27:07:212 minUnit.testTimerSet:  END                                                            :0.006447
>
> 20:27:13:618 minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:27:13:621 minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                           :0.003337
>
> 20:27:21:240 minUnit.testTimerSet:  START
> 20:27:21:244  Application.OnTime 'minUnit.testCallBack "testTimer","21:27:21"'                     :0.004301
> 20:27:21:246 minUnit.testTimerSet:  END                                                            :0.006274
>
> 20:27:33:946 ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeClose:  START
> 20:27:33:949  minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:27:33:951  minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                          :0.001921
> 20:27:33:953  minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:27:33:957  minUnit.testTimerKill:  END
> 20:27:33:957**ERROR: 1004: Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed                         :0.002433
> 20:27:33:963  minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:27:33:967  minUnit.testTimerKill:  END
> 20:27:33:967**ERROR: 1004: Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed                         :0.002230
> 20:27:33:972  Application.OnTime 0, "Nothing", , False
> 20:27:33:972**ERROR: 1004: Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed                         :0.024134
> 20:27:33:977  Application.Run 'minUnit.testCallBack "Application.Run","20:27:33"'                  :0.031184
> 20:27:33:983  minUnit.testCallBack:  START
> 20:27:35:995  minUnit.testCallBack:  END                                                           :2.012402
> 20:27:35:997  Application.OnTime Now() 'minUnit.testCallBack "Application.OnTime Now()","20:27:35"':2.051651
> 20:27:35:999 ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeClose:  END                                               :2.053604
> ```

Trace for closing with .Close by running closeWorkbook (should have thrown the first error at 20:30:11:979)...

> ```
> 20:29:48:201 minUnit.testTimerSet:  START
> 20:29:48:204  Application.OnTime 'minUnit.testCallBack "testTimer","21:29:48"'                     :0.003342
> 20:29:48:206 minUnit.testTimerSet:  END                                                            :0.005207
>
> 20:29:51:942 minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:29:51:945 minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                           :0.002946
>
> 20:29:55:444 minUnit.testTimerSet:  START
> 20:29:55:448  Application.OnTime 'minUnit.testCallBack "testTimer","21:29:55"'                     :0.003535
> 20:29:55:450 minUnit.testTimerSet:  END                                                            :0.005446
>
> 20:30:11:966 ThisWorkbook.closeWorkbook:  START
> 20:30:11:971  ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeClose:  START
> 20:30:11:973   minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:30:11:975   minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                         :0.001994
> 20:30:11:979   minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:30:11:981   minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                         :0.001847
> 20:30:11:983   minUnit.testTimerKill:  START
> 20:30:11:986   minUnit.testTimerKill:  END                                                         :0.002271
> 20:30:11:988   Application.OnTime 0, "Nothing", , False                                            :0.016905
> 20:30:11:991   Application.Run 'minUnit.testCallBack "Application.Run","20:30:11"'                 :0.019140
> 20:30:11:996   minUnit.testCallBack:  START
> 20:30:13:976   minUnit.testCallBack:  END                                                          :1.979131
> 20:30:13:977   Application.OnTime Now() 'minUnit.testCallBack "Application.OnTime Now()","20:30:13"':2.005963
> 20:30:13:985  ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeClose:  END                                              :2.013265
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications. For testing purposes we only need a msgbox to notice whether the routine has been run/stopped correctly.

In standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date ' Needs to be a public/global variable

Public Sub TimerStart()
    dTime = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Application.OnTime dTime, "TimerStart"

    MsgBox "Callback " & TimeValue(dTime)
End Sub

Public Sub TimerKill()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "TimerStart", , False
End Sub

Public Sub CloseWB()
    TimerKill
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Run "CloseWB"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "TimerStart"
End Sub
```

This works for me. Following scenarios have been tested:

- Run "TimerSet" manually > Wait for a few msgboxes > Run "TimerKill" manually.
- Run "TimerSet" manually > Wait for a few msgboxes > Close workbook.
- Open workbook > Wait for a few msgboxes > Close workbook.
- Open workbook > Wait for a few msgboxes > Close workbook using the CloseWB macro.

What I've found is:

- Running "TimerKill" from Workbook_BeforeClose **does not work**. The workbook reopens.
- Running "CloseWB" from Workbook_BeforeClose **works**.

I'm sorry I can't explain **why** this is. However, it should work for you now.

Comment: testTimerKill was indeed faulty paste... thanks for pointing that out, now corrected. I'll cross-check the rest of your analysis and report back.

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover the failure mode which is when the workbook is closed using code `ThisWorkbook.Close`

Comment: @CoolBlue I have updated my answer, including a solution for your request. Please try it and report back. Somehow, killing the timer before running the timer again, solves this problem. Kind of funky, since the timer has already passed, however it was the only way the timer would stop from the CloseWB macro.

Comment: Tack sa mycket for having a stab at this but when I ran [your code](https://app.box.com/s/5q4cwyay3jnukitz68da) I got the same result: after running closeWB workbook re-opens on next timer. I'm running Office 2013 on Windows 7, same result for x32 and x64.

Comment: Also tested with Office 2010 on Windows XP: same result as per my original question.

Comment: Updated answer. Man, that OnTime can be a pain in the. Seems like it doesn't work to run the TimerKill from Workbook_BeforeClose event. It needs to run a separate macro that runs TimerKill instead. Perhaps it has something to do with the modules (ThisWorkbook being a private one). Anyways, hope it works now. I'm running Office 2010 btw.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming.  Your answer is very neat.  Conclusion is: Application.OnTime is completely ignored after the Workbook_BeforeClose event handler has been entered. My question is: Why? And we just don't know... Microsoft?

Comment: Although I cannot answer WHY it happens, I did provide a solution to your problem. I've upped this question though, hoping someone else can explain the weird behaviour of Workbook_BeforeClose.